# What algorithm could I have used to solve this interview question?

Tags: algorithm

I got this question in an interview and it really stumped me so I'm trying to figure out how to solve this. My initial thought was to try to figure out what the grid looks like if days = 1, then days = 2 and so on to days = 4, but I don't how to make that jump from day = 1 where every blank is filled to day 2. Or if this is even the right approach?

An ant colony takes 1 day to expand in every direction (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). Given a grid of empty spaces and rocks where ants can not pass through, denoted by 'R', and a number of days for the ants to fill up every empty space, what is the minimum number of starting positions that the ants need?

Ex 1:

```
grid = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],        days = 3
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

Solution = 1
 day 1: [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],   
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", "A", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

 day 2: [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " "],   
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", " "],
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", " "],
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

 day 3: [["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],   
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]]
```

Ex 2:

```
grid = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", " "],        days = 4
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", "R"],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
        [" ", "R", " ", "R", "R", "R"],
        [" ", "R", "R", "R", " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

Solution = 3

day 1:  [[" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", "A"], 
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", " "],
         [" ", " ", "A", " ", "R", "R"],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", "R", " ", "R", "R", "R"],
         [" ", "R", "R", "R", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", "A", " ", " ", " "]]

day 2:  [[" ", " ", " ", " ", "R", "A"], 
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", "R", "A"],
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", "R", "R"],
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", "R", " ", "R", "R", "R"],
         [" ", "R", "R", "R", " ", " "],
         [" ", "A", "A", "A", " ", " "]]

day 3:  [["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "A"], 
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "R"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", " "],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", " "],
         [" ", "R", " ", "R", "R", "R"],
         ["A", "R", "R", "R", "A", " "],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", " "]]

day 4:  [["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "A"], 
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "R", "R"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "R", "A", "R", "R", "R"],
         ["A", "R", "R", "R", "A", "A"],
         ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]]
```

Comment: General observations: for each distinct zone separated by rocks you need at least one starting point, giving a lower boundary. Brute forcing all possible combinations will certainly explode for large grids. In this case, a large grid still rather small.

Comment: It's probably best to backtrack this from a full grid and go backwards, subtracting the most amount of coherent colonies possible.

Comment: What are the data constraints?

Comment: As mentioned by infinitezero, start by finding [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). Within each component, use [an algorithm that finds the shortest path between each pair of nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm). For example, if the limit is 3 days, and the shortest path from A to B is 8 days, then you'll need to choose at least one of the points that's within distance 3 from A, and another point that's within distance 3 from B. From there, things get complicated, because 2 ants are necessary, but may not be sufficient.

Comment: To be precise, what you're left with is a problem similar to the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: @user3386109 What the OP would be left with is a problem that is *reducible* to the set cover problem; the fact that set cover is NP-complete doesn't say much about the OP's problem.

Comment: @user3386109 I doubt the secret to happiness is related to editing internet comments!

Comment: I would have asked if a greedy approximation would be sufficient. Note the set cover reduction. Note the brute force solution. And said, "I suspect that branch and bound would actually solve this efficiently in practice, but I'd have to look up how to implement that."